# How do I save links to files or websites from my html browser using JS without it being reset every time

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, hyperlink

I am working on a project that would allow the client to save a link to the webpage without having to do any backend coding. I have html and js written to allow this, but the js resets when you leave the page and the link goes away. How could I make these links permanent after addition even if the page is reloaded, etc.? FYI: I am a novice at coding, so dumbing down answers for me is appreciated.

Here is my html and js code:

```html
<form action="#" id="createElForm">
    <label for="" style="display: block;">Write or paste a link</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="www.example.com" id="linkInput" required>
    <label for="" style="display: block;">Text to display</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example Text" id="textInput" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" style="display: block;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#createElForm");
const table = document.querySelector("table");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const linkValue = document.querySelector("#linkInput").value;
    const textValue = document.querySelector("#textInput").value;
    const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    const newCell = document.createElement("td");
    const newLink = document.createElement("a");

    newLink.href = linkValue;
    newLink.target = "_blank";
    newLink.style.color = "blue";
    newLink.textContent = textValue;

    newCell.appendChild(newLink);
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    table.appendChild(newRow);

    form.reset();
});
```

Comment: You can save your variables in **local storage**. Once you open up the page again, check if you have already saved links in a local storage, if so, update these variables.

Comment: You'd have to store the data somewhere.  `localStorage` or cookies are common options.  Applications by default don't "remember" data, but they can save data to somewhere and read data from somewhere.  It's just a matter of where you decide to store it.

Comment: Though it's also worth noting that data saved in a localStorage and cookies can be lost if you decide to clear your cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can save and retrieve data using localstorage

So, to save data

```js
localStorage.setItem(linkValue, textValue);
```

and to recieve data

```js
localStorage.getItem(linkValue);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

### Working example using the localStorage property.

---

#### Saving data

The key is to create a variable that will temporarily store the links.
In this example, I named my variable `savedLinks`.

> Since we represent the link as a custom `textValue`. It's best to store the links' data as an Object datatype because it allows us to use `textValue` as a unique key identifier, which can be used to prevent duplicate link-names on the DOM.

Once variable `savedLinks` is updated, save it to the **localStorage**.

For example: `localStorage.setItem("links")`.

> I decided to store `savedLinks` variable as `links` in my localStorage, but you can name it to whatever best suits you. I also decided to update and save the `savedLinks` data using a custom function `saveLink()` as it allows me to later disclude further link inclusion when it's a duplicate.

```
function saveLink(textValue, linkValue) {
  
  if (textValue in savedLinks)
  {
    // return false, with a popup message (alert)
    alert(`Link with textValue '${textValue}' already exists.`);
    return false;
  }

  // Include the link into the 'savedLinks' variable,
  // Then, save 'savedLinks' variable to the localStorage.
  savedLinks[textValue] = linkValue;
  localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(savedLinks));

  return true;
}
```

**Note that:**

- LocalStorage stores key value pairs as strings only.
- LocalStorage data can be removed manually using the DevTools (section: storage), and by clearing the browser's cache.
- Also, the localStorage data is saved uniquely to the specific browser. Hence, what was saved in Chrome cannot be accessed by Firefox.

---

#### Importing saved data

Once the localStorage variable is set, we can access it using the command `localStorage.getItem("links")`.

We can try retrieving localStorage data at any time because If the code fails, it will return a `null` value. We can use this to declare the variable `savedLinks` to an empty Object like so:

`var savedLinks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("links")) || {};`

> JSON.parse() will construct the, saved in localStorage data, to a JavaScript value or object. Without it, we would have to deal with a string datatype instead.

Since we always get `savedLinks` initialized to an Object. We can simply loop through available keys and import the links to the DOM.

```
Object.keys(savedLinks).forEach(key => {
  let textValue = key;
  let linkValue = savedLinks[key];
  createLink(textValue, linkValue);
});
```

---

#### Additions

> I've decided to secure the links at `createLink()` function. This is because when I tried to access the imported to the DOM links, I was redirected to a local directory instead of the specified address. However, I did so most importantly because the inclusion of **TLS** (Transport Layer Security) and **SSL** (Secure Sockets Layer) improves clients' security.

---

#### Working example

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" id="createElForm">
  <label for="" style="display: block;">Write or paste a link</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="www.example.com" id="linkInput" required>
  <label for="" style="display: block;">Text to display</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Example Text" id="textInput" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" style="display: block;">Submit</button>
</form>
  
<table></table>
```

**JS - Functions**

```
function createLink(textValue, linkValue) {
  // If TLS or SSL is NOT included in the link
  // Then, secure the link's connection with TLS protocol 
  if (!linkValue.includes('https://')) {
    if (!linkValue.includes('http://')) {
      linkValue = 'https://' + linkValue;
    }
  }

  // Construct the link and append it to the <table>

  let newRow  = document.createElement("tr");
  let newCell = document.createElement("td");
  let newLink = document.createElement("a");

  newLink.href = linkValue;
  newLink.target = "_blank";
  newLink.style.color = "blue";
  newLink.textContent = textValue;

  newCell.appendChild(newLink);
  newRow.appendChild(newCell);
  table.appendChild(newRow);
}


function saveLink(textValue, linkValue) {
  
  if (textValue in savedLinks)
  {
    // return false, with a popup message (alert)
    alert(`Link with textValue '${textValue}' already exists.`);
    return false;
  }

  // Include the link into the 'savedLinks' variable,
  // Then, save 'savedLinks' variable to the localStorage.
  savedLinks[textValue] = linkValue;
  localStorage.setItem("links", JSON.stringify(savedLinks));

  return true;
}
```

**JS - Main Script**

```
const form  = document.querySelector("#createElForm");
const table = document.querySelector("table");
// Get saved 'links' Object from the localStorage.
// Otherwise, set variable 'savedLinks' to an empty Object.
const savedLinks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("links")) || {};


// Create any saved links to the DOM
Object.keys(savedLinks).forEach(key => {
  let textValue = key;
  let linkValue = savedLinks[key];
  createLink(textValue, linkValue);
});


form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let linkValue = document.querySelector("#linkInput").value;
  let textValue = document.querySelector("#textInput").value;

  // Try to save the link into the localStorage.
  // If the link is already saved, stop this script. 
  if (!saveLink(textValue, linkValue)) return;
  
  createLink(textValue, linkValue);
  form.reset();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

(excuse my english and speling)

create a javascript object and pt that information in it,
then save the object to your lacal storage, then upon page reload get the object and create the link

```
// create a function that saves the link info
function saveLinkInfo(href,target,color,textContent){
  
  // put the parametors in an object to make a link object
  const link = {href,target,color,textContent};

  // if you have links in your localstorage get them with the "localStorage.getItem("linkInfo")" method
  // use "JSON.parse()" to convert them into an object 
  //if you dont have any create an object, the below line does all that
  var linkInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("linkInfo")) || {};

  // create a unique id for the new link
  // below i do this by geting an array of all the keys of values in the links info variable with the "Object.keys(linkInfo)" method
  // then i get the legth of the array and add 1, this will create a unique id like in sql auto encrement ids
  var linkId = Object.keys(linkInfo).length + 1;
  
  // add the link object to the linkInfo Object using the id we created as the key
  linkInfo[linkId] = link;

  // turn the linkinfo onject to a jason string
  // we are doing this becase you can only save strings to the loacal storage
  linkInfo = JSON.stringify(linkInfo);

  // save the linkinfo stringified object to your localstorage
  localStorage.setItem("linkInfo",linkInfo);
}
```

this function creates the links and returns atable row (tr element) with the links

```
// create the links on page reload
function createLinks(){
  // get the linkInfo object and use "JSON.parse()" to turn it back into an object
  //  remember we turned it into a Json string before saving it in the "saveLinkInfo()" function
  const linkInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("linkInfo")) || {};
  const newRow = document.createElement("tr");
  const newCell = document.createElement("td");

  // loop through the object and create the link
  for(let key in linkInfo){
    if(linkInfo.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      
      const newLink  = document.createElement("a");
      newLink.href = linkInfo[key].href;
      newLink.target = linkInfo[key].target;
      newLink.style.color = linkInfo[key].color;
      newLink.textContent = linkInfo[key].textContent;

      newCell.appendChild(newLink);
      newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    }
  }
  
  // return the row
  return newRow;
}
```

if there is anything i need to clarify or if i misunderstood what you wanted to do please comment,